# Speed up F# compile with Reference Assembly

Tags: f#, fsc

I thought I'd try out speeding up my compiles with Reference Assemblies. So I add this to my projects:

```xml
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
```

But get a nasty error for my F# projects:

`error : Expected file "obj\Debug\net5.0\ref\xyz.dll" does not exist.`

It seems like F# doesn't support reference assemblies.

Will this be fixed?

Is there a way to do this with F# signature files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your are correct that the F# compiler does not support reference assemblies. I could find no mention of them in the documentation of [F# compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options).

There is an open feature request to add this support at https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3066. You could comment on that, if you think this would be a good feature to add to the F# compiler.

Comment: Nice find! I couldn't find anything useful with google AND my build time is getting painful.  Looks like they're looking into it...